# Retrieve min and max dates from MySQL when date is not stored as timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the earliest and latest dates from a table field.

These are the dates as stored.

01/30/2015
02/31/2014
10/26/2014
01/31/2015

Using these queries:

```
$sql = "SELECT MIN(closing_date) AS first_date FROM ft_form_8 WHERE closing_date >'' 
AND status = 'closed' AND nar_id = $nar_id  ";

$sql = "SELECT MAX(closing_date) AS last_date FROM ft_form_8 WHERE closing_date >'' 
AND status = 'closed' AND nar_id = $nar_id  ";
```

The first_date value when retrieved is: 01/30/2015
The last_date value when retrieved is: 10/26/2014

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest to change the way you store dates on the database, it will make it much easier to work with dates then.

Comment: Use the STR_TO_DATE() function when comparing the columns.  

Info here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: You could also cast the dates to timestamps..